# Python - Remove brackets, commas and quotation marks in a representation of a list

Tags: python, join, dictionary

I've looked at previous entries and they're relatively difficult to understand because of the code people have used. I've used the join function but it's not working. I am trying to join a list of lists into a single string, the output should have each joined sublist separated by a space:

```
Five = 5

Converted = [chr(i) for i in addof]

#converts the numbers into letters of a not mentioned here variable(addof)

grouped = [converted[i:i+five] for i in range(0, len(converted), five)]

#groups the letters into groups of five

print("".join(map(str, grouped)))

#trying to use the join function in order to remove brackets etc. but it doesnt work

####################### OUTPUT ######################

['V', 'r', 'p', 'h', 'z']['k', 'h', 'u', 'h', 'l']['q', 'o', 'd', 'P', 'd']['q', 'f', 'k', 'd', '/']['l', 'q', 'd', 's', 'o']['d', 'f', 'h', 'z', 'k']['r', 'v', 'h', 'q', 'd']['p', 'h', 'L', 'g', 'r']
```

Can anyone please help? 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by brackets, where are they coming from?

Comment: In the output you've got the square brackets, but I don't want those there.

Comment: Do you mean you have a list of lists and you want a single list or what exactly? If you add the original structure it will be a lot easier to understand what you want

Comment: You realise calling `map(str` on a list will give you the string representation of a list?

Comment: All I want is the brackets to be removed and the commas and the quotation marks from where I have clearly written ########## output ######. It is a list.  What I want is for it to just appear as Vrphz khuhl qodPd etc....

Comment: I got the whole map thing from something I saw on here and thought it would work but it didn't

Comment: you have a list of lists, if you `" ".join([''.join(sub) for sub in grouped])` that will give you a single string

Comment: That works thank you so much :)

Comment: Jus to make it clear: there are no brackets and commas in the list. There are brackets and commas in the _representation_ of a list.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
[''.join(x) for x in grouped]
```

Comment: that works but doesn't remove the square brackets at the front and end nor does it remove the quotation marks   Output : ['Vrphz', 'khuhl', 'qodPd', 'qfkd/', 'lqdso', 'dfhzk', 'rvhqd', 'phLgr', 'qrwfd', 'uhwru', 'hphpe', 'hu/dj', 'hqwoh', 'pdqol', 'yhgqr', 'worqj', 'djr/r', 'qhriw', 'krvhz', 'krkdv', 'dodqf', 'hdqgd', 'qflhq', 'wvklh', 'ogrqd', 'vkhoi', 'dqgnh', 'hsvdv', 'nlqq|', 'qdjdq', 'gdjuh', '|krxq', 'giruu', 'dflqj', '1']

Comment: do you need output without brackets and quotes, line by line ? try:           for i in [''.join(x) for x in grouped]: print i

Comment: Thanks for your help but I've got the solution now from Padraic Cunningham :)